# jQuery - How to show/hide dynamically generated html elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code. The html elements with the class ".acc_container" are created dynamically through an AJAX call, so they don't exist yet when the code `$('.acc_container').hide();` is executed. Is there something I can do here similar to the `.live` function for event binding?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acc_container').hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Sample.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {
        //Tags with ".acc_container" class created here
```

Comment: Why not just hide it in the success callback function?

Comment: Good idea John. I think that will work too. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control it easily through `CSS`.

```
.acc_container{
   display:none;
}
```

Whenever you want to `show` then use jQuery `$(".acc_container").show();`

Answer (score 0):

I like ShankarSangoli's answer, however just be aware that ALL containers with that class will be shown, not just last one... You might want to control visibility via ID rather than class, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide created element in AJAX callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Sample.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (xml) {

        //Tags with ".acc_container" class created here

        **$('.acc_container').hide();**
   });
```